# What is the importance of fast (Vrat)?

Tags: vrata

Being a Brahmin, I do observe Fast. But literally,I don't know its importance. I wondered, how being hungry whole day could fulfill your wish. Do `GOD` pleases when people are hungry?

As, I am a Punjabi and I also studied in Gurbani

Shri Guru Nanak Dev ji said:

> Chhod Ann (food,bhojan) Jo Kare pakhand, Na suhagan ( married ) Na oh rand (widow women)

So, I just want to know how being hungry can fulfill our wish ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Hinduism.SE. I've closed your question as a duplicate because I don't think this question is any different from the one I've linked with,  if you have any doubts, feel free to comment. Thank you.

Comment: Also, a confusion here, are you a brahmin or a punjabi?

Comment: In the answer shown by Mr. Alien, there is adequate description of what is the reason for fasting. as for the question 'does God get pleased if people are hungry? how does being hungry fulfill anybody's wishes' I would like to ask a clarification. Is 'fasting' in question done in order to fulfill somebody's wishes? I am sure fasting is done by different people for different reasons. not all people fast in order to get their wishes fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks @Alien. I am a Brahmin but belong to punjab.Thats why i said that,